# check size of memory before exporting it to .php file

Tags: php, file, size

I wrote a PHP script that index the contents of my site and stores it in multi-dimensional arrays. Then I export what is in the memory, that array, to a .php file to include and access later.

How can I check the size of the memory or the size of the memory associated with the variable I'm exporting before I save it to a file.

For example, if less than 1gb, export. Else, do nothing and erase what's in memory associated with variable $x.

How could I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with:

```
memory_get_usage()
```

call this function before and after create your array, and take the difference.

```
echo "At the start we're using (in bytes): ",
     memory_get_usage() , "\n<br>";

... array...

echo "After, we're using (in bytes): ",
     memory_get_usage(),"\n<br>";
```

or

```
$before  = memory_get_usage();
... array ...
$after = memory_get_usage();
echo round(($after-$before)/1024/1024, 2)." MB\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with this

```
$filename = 'somefile.txt';
$filesize = filesize($filename);  //'in bytes'
if($filesize < 1GB)  // means if($filesize < 1024)
   //Do export
else
   echo 'Exceeded 1GB';
```

Comment: I want to check what the file size would be. Before I export it to file. How can I check size of memory taken up for variable $x? What does `…means ($filesize < 1024)` mean? Why can't I do just `if($filesize < 1024)`?

Comment: before exporting you can get the filename right..??using that check the filesize and do the remaining stuff

Comment: Okay. $x is the variable I'm exporting. The array.

Answer (score 0):

How will you save the array to the file? If you are going to serialize the array, than you may do that first (if you have enough ram) and then check the string length of the serialized variable before saving it to file.